# how to pass data and use user input in method calls

Tags: java, methods

I am having the most difficult time understanding method calls that use outside variables.  Here is what I'm trying to do in print form, and below I'll paste two attempts.  I keep getting loops of the same error messages when i try to fix what I'm doing.  I'm also wanting a user to enter a number to choose a selection, which I'll need to use elsewhere.  This can all be done easily in main, but I'm trying to practice passing arguments back and forth...

Attached is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utlh1.jpg) detailing what I'm trying to do, and below is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SandwichShop {
    private String MOTTO = "Come back for another!";
    private int rye = 150;
    private int white = 120;
    public int decision;

    public void breadCals (int r, int w) {
        int sel;
        r = rye;
        w = white;
        if (sel == 1) {
            System.out.println("you entered 1 " + r);
        } else {
            System.out.println("you entered 2 ");
        }
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter ");
        int decision = input.nextInt();

        SandwichShop.decision();
    }
}
```

OR

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestSandwich {
    private int calsR;
    private int calsW;
    private int ryeB;
    private int whiteB;
    private int decision = 0;
    private int selection;
    private String MOTTO = "Come back for another!";

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        breadType();
        //TestSandwich decision = new TestSandwich();
        //decision.Display();
     }

     public static int breadType() {
         int ryeB = 1;
         int whiteB = 2;
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         //System.out.println("What type of bread do you want?");
         //System.out.println("Please enter 1 for Rye and 2 for White");
         int decision = input.nextInt();
         return decision;
     }

     public void bCals(){
         int calsR = 150;
         int calsW = 120;
     }

     public void Display(int decision) {
         int selection = decision;
         System.out.println("What type of bread do you want?");
         System.out.println("Please enter 1 for Rye and 2 for White");
         if (selection == 1) {
             System.out.println("Rye bread has " + calsR + " calories.");
         } else {
             System.out.println("White bread has " + calsW + " calories."); 
         }
         //System.out.println(MOTTO);
     }

     //!main - btype - display -bcals 

     /*

     public static int calsAmt( int cals) {

         TestSandwich.display();


     }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick change of your first code so you might understand a bit more. I tried to keep most of your code.

```
public class FirstClass {
public static int decision;     
public static void main(String[] args) { 

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter ");
decision = input.nextInt();

System.out.println(decision);

SecondClass.breadCals();    //gets the method 
}}
```

and second class

```
Public class SecondClass{

private static int rye = 150;
private static int white = 120; //static for a call like that
public int decision;

 public static  void breadCals () { 
   //method needs to be static to call it like i did
  int sel=FirstClass.decision;
  int  r = rye;
  int  w = white;
  if (sel == 1) System.out.println("you entered 1 " + r);
  else if(sel== 2) System.out.println("you entered 2 "+ w);
  else System.out.println("Wrong number"); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I’ll take another stab at it.